# Keeping a Codeigniter project updated with Git

Tags: git, codeigniter

I am working on a Codeigniter project and I'd like to keep the system folder and the config in the application folder updated, but I am not familiar with Git and I don't know what I need to do.

The Codeigniter project is structured like this:

```
/application
  - /config
/system
/index.php
```

I thought I could simply replace the system folder but it relies on some updates to the config files in the application as well. I keep all of my project in the application folder.

I have some custom stuff in my config files, so it could be time consuming to do it by hand.

Can someone explain to me like I'm 5 how to get started?

The full path to the project is `C:\xampp\htdocs\MYSITE\system`

The Codeigniter repos is at https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter

Answer (score 2):

I found this tutorial incredibly easy to follow and use. My repos all work perfectly even though they are using CodeIgniter.

http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto